# How to do a mass import of ovpn files?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I need to mass import a lot of OVPN files that ProtonVPN makes me download. However it'd be very very annoying to put the passwords for each one in the GUI app as I tried to do. There are more than 50 ovpn files.

Is there a way to mass import them with password already? (all of them have the same user and password)

Comment: This answer on the SE U&L site may help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/301856/27043

Comment: @KevinBowen I tried that but it still asks me for the password on the first connection. I even tried to give the password but it keeps asking again after some time, no connection.

Comment: @KevinBowen I did a manual import and manual username/password insertion. The password is never stored on the config file, even after I manually add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, at least for Proton VPN files. Here's everything:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456889/271974